# Why the catch method doesn't work on second fetch?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, fetch-api

```
//Promise

"use strict";
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector(`.countries`);
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-country");
const renderCountry = function (data, className = "") {
  const html = `<article class="country ${className}">
      <img class="country__img" src="${data.flag}" />
      <div class="country__data">
        <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
        <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
        <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(
          +data.population / 1000000
        ).toFixed(1)} people</p>
        <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages[0].name}</p>
        <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies[0].symbol}</p>
      </div>
    </article>`;
  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  btn.style.opacity = 0;
};

const renderErrorMessage = function (msg) {
  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", msg);
};

const getJSON = function (url, errMsg = "An error has been caught") {
  return fetch(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`${errMsg}: ${response.status}`);
    return response.json();
  });
};

const getCountryData = function (country) {
  getJSON(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`, "Country not found!")
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      renderCountry(data[0]);
      const neighbor = data[0].borders[0];
      // const neighbor = 'sdvjnkvaf';

      if (!neighbor) throw new Error(`No neighbor for this country!`);

      return getJSON(
        `https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${neighbor}`,
        "Country not found!"
      );
    })
    .then((data) => renderCountry(data[0]))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      renderErrorMessage(`Something went wrong, ${err.message}. Try again!`);
    })
    .finally(() => (countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1));
};

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  getCountryData("portugal");
});
```

I'm new to JS and I've just started to work with promises.
I'm using **https://restcountries.com/v2** API to get countries data by passing their name and I also chain another promise to get the specified country's neighbor. As I mention in `renderErrorMessage` method, if the main or either neighbor country wasn't found it should say 'Country not found', and if the main was a country without any neighbors it should say 'No neighbors for this country'.

But it doesn't show the neighbor country at all! Even if the main one is an appropriate country such as Portugal with Spain as it's neighbor!

[image: This is the error I get every time I click the button]

Where's my mistake? Is it about the way I chain promises or my error handling?
Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: The error is generated because the argument passed to `renderCountry`, `data[0]`, is undefined, like it says in the error message in the image posted offsite. Tip: it's best to post error messages as text in the question. Does the log of the `data` argument passed to the `then` handler for the promise returned by `getJason(...)` show a zero property like you would see for an array or collection?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem was exactly about data argument. It's not an array so i removed [ ] from renderCountry's argument and it's been solved.‍♀️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the "name" api endpoint at the first request and the "alpha" api endpoint when you retrieve the neighbor by his code.

The first request gives an array as a response but the second with the "alpha" api endpoint gives a single object corresponding exactly to the code you give.

So instead of referring to the country as data[0] you should refer to it as data

```
const getCountryData = function (country) {
        getJSON(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`, "Country not found!")
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            renderCountry(data[0]);
            const neighbor = data[0].borders[0];
            // const neighbor = 'sdvjnkvaf';

            if (!neighbor) throw new Error(`No neighbor for this country!`);

            return getJSON(
              `https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${neighbor}`,
              "Country not found!"
            );
          })
          .then((data) => // retrieving a single object {} here not array []
             renderCountry(data)
          )
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            renderErrorMessage(`Something went wrong, ${err.message}. Try again!`);
          })
          .finally(() => (countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1));
      };
```